# Using ActionBarSherlock without Holo theme on Honeycomb and above

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I'm building an Android app that should be able to run on Android 2.1 and above. The `minSdkVersion` is set to *7*, and the `targetSdkVersion` is set to *14*. In order to have ActionBar functionality, I am using the ActionBarSherlock library and setting the theme of the application to a derivative of `Theme.Sherlock` (etc.), as required.

Aside from providing an ActionBar, I notice that when I run the app on a Honeycomb/ICS device, some of the other widgets and dialogs now have a different (i.e. Holo) appearance. I want to have an ActionBar but keep the normal, non-Holo Android theme - the Holo styling does not fit well with the rest of the app. EditText views in particular look significantly different.

I see that ActionBarSherlock defines some custom themes in *values-11* (Honeycomb) and *values-14* (ICS), which inherit from *Theme.Holo*. There are also custom styles in *values-14* which map the ABS styles to the native ones (since the native ActionBar is used in ICS+).

I have found that I have to do at least the following things:

1. Disable the custom themes for *values-11* and *values-14* - this stops Holo widgets/dialogs appearing.
2. Disable the use of the native implementation of the ActionBar for ICS+ - this stops the crashing on ICS since it relies on the native ActionBar provided as part of Holo theme. This requires modification of the library.
3. Disable the custom styles for *values-14* - this messed with the look/styling of the compatibility ActionBar.

I am not sure if there are other issues that I have missed. Has anyone found a good way to use the non-Holo Android theme with ActionBarSherlock, without modifying the library? Are there any problems with using the compatibility ActionBar in ICS and above?